# Reflection how to pass values to parameters based on getparameters and cast return object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection

1.
i have one class method with parameters.

this parameters can change it can be one or two.

i have to invoke this method in runtime.

i have parameterinfo .

i need to check how many parameters are there and what type it is and then need to invoke it.

now i am passing 2 values manually without considering parameterinfo.

2.

the invoking method is returning one class object which have one property.

this class can have any number of property.

any changes to this class should not affect my invoke method.

i have to cast the invoke result and get the property values.
example 
**House.currentDay**
in future more property can be added

i have class library
with class

```
    namespace ReflectionCALlingproject
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public House GetResultsByReflection(int HouseNumb,int pincode)
        {
            House house = new House ();
            House.currentDay=DateTime.Now;
            return house;
        }

    }
}
```

i have to call this class dynamically at runtime and need to get the currentDay.

```
 namespace callingproject
{

     public string test()
            {
         int HouseNumb= 31231123;
         int pincode= 124124124;
        string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"bin\ReflectionCALlingproject.dll");         
                   Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
                   Type type = assembly.GetType("ReflectionCALlingproject.Class1");
                    if (type != null)
                    {
                        MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("GetResultsByReflection");
                        if (methodInfo != null)
                        {
                        ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
                       object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);

            object[] parametersArray = new object[] { HouseNumb, pincode};   //need to pass this values based on the parameterinfo.       
                            result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray );


                        }
                    }
                    return result.ToString();
    //result is House object how can i get the property from it.
    }

}
```

i have to pass the parameters based on the parameterinfo.

if am changing the calling method parameters it should work properly.

how can i pass values based on the parameterinfo.

how can i cast the result to the specified house class?

**ReflectionCALlingproject.dll will build after callingproject.
so build error will occur.
so we have to use reflection and call the dll dynamically**

Comment: Welcome to reflection, you lose all (compile time) type safety, so you cant do things like cast to the type because you dont know the type. Also your question is a little unclear ("how can i pass values based on the parameterinfo."). Maybe describe what you're trying to *acheive* rather than *how you're trying to achieve it* and you'll get an answer which helps you.

Comment: i have added more details please check and tell me if still its unclear

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What do you actually want to do with ParameterInfo? Does passing by object not work? On your second question - how would you know (at compile time) what type you want to cast to?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Still totally unclear. Why do you need reflection in the first place (for starters)

Comment: i have to call this dll in run time , i cant call it directly.

Comment: By the definition of the word, that's not true. It's obviously *possible* to call it directly, and you *can* do that, but for some business or technical reason you've decided you *shouldn't*. So the real question is, why did you decide you should call it dynamically at runtime?

Comment: Ive given an answer but I echo what I said earlier - try to describe what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: the invoking project will build after the calling project.so if amcalling it directly build errors will come

Comment: Why dont you just change the order they are compiling? If you reference them in the right way this just happens automatically!

Comment: its existing project build order. we cant change it as per business

Comment: Youre a developer, what does a business care what order you compile your projects in. You're doing them a disservice by solving this "issue" in a roundabout, easily breakable way.

Comment: no actually we have our own framework ,so before building the web project we have to build our framework project. ina way project 2 has working above project1 code. i think u got me.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS**

Ok, based on your comments explaining why you need reflection, it sounds like there is a much easier way.

Basically, method `GetResultsByReflection` is in a class in `WebProject1`. Now, in your `FrameworkProject1`, you want to call that method. This doesn't work because you can't do circular references. This kind of scenario happens often, but it's *not* a good use case for reflection. Instead, it's a code smell which indicates your projects are not organized well.

There are 2 possible solutions.

1. Move `GetResultsByReflection` (and its containing type, if appropriate) to `FrameworkProject1`. Since your web project must already reference your framework project, this should be a simple solution
2. Move `GetResultsByReflection` to a new project (say `UtilityProject1`). Then reference `UtilityProject` from both `FrameworkProject1` and `WebProject1`.

**Original Answer**

One of the challenges of reflection is that you can't be as dynamic as you're trying to be.

1. If you know what you're looking for, you can check using parameters.Length, or by looking at individual members to see if they are the type you expect. However, you can't make this fully dynamic and be confident it will work. Imagine the GetResultsByReflection method is updated so it now also takes a String parameter. Your calling code has no way of knowing what to pass. If the contract of the underlying method is changed in a breaking way, your reflection code will always have to be updated.
2. Are you 100% guaranteed that the method will return a House object? If so, you can just cast it as (House)result.

I'm a little confused on the premise. It sounds like you know exactly where the dll will be, what the name of the method will be, what the contract will be, what parameters will be required, what response will be returned. Given all of those facts, why do you need reflection? If you can really describe your root problem, there may be a much easier solution which gives you everything you want at compile time without the extra risk and maintenance problems reflection inherently introduces.

Comment: my main problem is my project structure will build project 1 first then project2. i am using reflection to call project 2 in project1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll have a go at answering this even though I think your question is still not clear - chances are this answer may not help you as I think what you have is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

---

> now i am passing 2 values manually without considering parameterinfo.

You already know how to get `ParameterInfo[]` using `GetParameters()`. You can interrogate this object to find the number, and type, of parameters required

> how can i cast the result to the specified house class

It depends, if you know in advance that your method will return a `House` object you can cast it directly.

```
House result = (House)methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray );
```

This is the case with a common use of reflection - the plug-in architecture. You would begin by defining an interface (say `IMyPlugin`), expect all plugin developers to implement your interface and instantiate a plugin using reflection but cast it to `IMyPluin`.

If you do not know in advance what the result is of your reflected `Invoke` call, then all you will know about the result is that it is `object`. Your only option for reading parameters is to continue to use reflection.

```
object result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray );
PropertyInfo myProp = result.GetType().GetProperty("currentDay");
var currentDay = myProp.Invoke(result,null);
```

But you're in an ever continuing cycle, you cant know the result of `currentDay` at compile time any better than you knew `House`.

Reflection is a last resort, and has specific purposes. If the concepts are confusing you how to use them, you're almost certainly using them for the wrong reasons.

Comment: can u just explain have to loop through parameterinfo and pass the parameters based on parameterinfo.

Comment: @Lijo Im not even sure how you want me to answer that - the array returned from `GetParameters()` is instances of `ParameterInfo`. Each one has a `Name` property, and a `ParameterType` property. What you do with that information is up to you, im not sure how you think this is some magic bullet which will somehow stop your code breaking as soon as someone changes the method - it wont!